# VB6 Database operations slow when multiple users connect to the database

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao

I am currently using VB6 to connect to a MS access DB using DAO and I’m experiencing a very noticeable speed reduction when a 2nd user connects to the Database.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

- Open the Database from computer A by logging into the software
- Add records to the database via the software (takes about .4 seconds)
- A second user logs into the software (Computer B), ie: this opens the database, displays todays transactions, but the user does nothing else
- On Computer A, repeat the operation of adding records, now the operation takes approximately 6 seconds

Further info…

- the operation continues to take aprox 6 seconds, even after Computer B logs out of the software
- if you close and reopen the application from Computer A the operation returns to taking only .4 seconds to execute!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: There might be a memory leak due to Computer B logging out not being handled correctly. Could you share your code?

Comment: If both users can run queries on the back-end at the same time and at a decent speed, it could be a problem with the front-end. I understand that it is not usual to have users connect directly to the back-end, but it should be a viable test.

Comment: I'm with Remou, if well designed; a split aceess solution can work with up to 15 - 20 users at a push. How complex is the software; is it just a particular area that is slow; or is it everything; has it been designed for multiple users, do you have a code sample from a slow section?

Answer (score 1):

That is the way MS Access works.  While it *kind of* supports multiple users, and *kind of* supports placing the DB on a file share so multiple PCs can access it, it does neither really well.  And if you are doing both (multi-user and over a network to a file share) then I feel for your pain.

The answer is to run the upgrade wizard and convert this to an MS SQL Server instance.  MS SQL Server Express edition is a good choice to replace Acess in the case.  Note that you can still keep all of your code and reports etc you have in Access, only the data needs to be moved.

---

Just to be clear on the differences, in MS Access when you read data from the database, all of the data *required to perform your query* is read from a file by your program, *no server-side processing is done*.  If that data resides on a network, you are pulling that data across your network.  If there are multiple users, you have an additional overhead of locking.  Each users program/process effectively dialogs with the program/process of the other users via file I/O (writing lock info into the networked file or files).  And if the network I/O times out or has other issues then those files can become corrupted.

In SQL Server, it is the SQL Server engine that manages the data requests and only returns the data required.  It also manages the locks and can detect when a client has disconnected or timed out to clean up, which reduces issues caused by multiple users on a network.

Comment: I am afraid this is not true. Switching to MS SQL Server is expensive - even the free version is expensive, and it is not a cure-all for network or code problems. MS Access is a good choice for a small number of users.

Comment: I can only speak to my own experience, and that is multi-user in a networked environment has intermittent performance and locking issues.  Not sure what expense you are referring to in regards to SQL Express, unless you mean having a box to run it on.  And you can almost buy a PC to run it on cheaper and the edition MS Office that includes Access.

Comment: Access (Jet/ACE) to use as a back-end is free. If the OP is having problems with two users and MS Access, I very much doubt that a new database is going to fix the problem.

Comment: It very well might if it is locking related (either locking within Access or at the physical file level).  And as always here on SO, it is *an* answer, it might not be **the** answer :)

Comment: I am afraid it is not an *accurate* answer. it contains some very old misconceptions. For example "all of the data is read from a file by your program" - this is only true if you have no indexes and a badly structured query. It is just as bad with SQL Server and a bad query, so changing the DB will not solve this problem. :)

Comment: Perhaps *all* is an overly broad simplification.  But even using an index there is no magic.  Any kind of read is done over the network.  The process reads the index information (pulling it across the network), then uses that to read the desired rows.  And given any non-trivial SQL it is likely reading a lot of indexes and metadata just to know what real data needs to be read.  All logic is done locally so any data needed to perform that logic is pulled.  It **is** accurate to state that SQL Server is more efficient in the amount of data pulled across the network.

Comment: If the table has a million rows, and we pull something by invoice number then only the ONE ROW of data is pulled down the network pipe.  (and a very tiny few leaf chops of the balanced btree index). So using linked table the SQL server or linked table to a file share means we effectively ONLY PULL THE ONE ROW DOWN across the network.  Furthermore if you bother to read the post then how come on that same network the user points out network performance is fine with one user if this is about too much data being pulled over the network then? (kind of blows your theory out don't it?).

Comment: Personally I think it is the locking.  Once a second user accesses Access it starts tracking locking (the old ldb, though not sure if the current vs of Access still uses that exact mechanism).  Even if all other users disconnect it is still in that mode, until all users close out and the locks are cleared.  Then upon reconnect you are in single-user mode.  The long comments here about data were just responses to comments from Remou in which we were more discussing pros/cons of multi-user Access on a network.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem with our VB3 / Jet DB 2.5 application when we transitioned to using newer file servers.

The problem is "opportunistic locking" : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296264?wa=wsignin1.0

Albert is probably describing the same thing ; the server will permit one client exclusive access of a file, but when another chimes in, this exclusive access will "thrash" between them, causing delays as the client with the oplock flushes all it's local cache to the server before the other client can access the file.

This may also be why you're getting good performance with one client - if it takes an oplock, it can cache all the data locally.

This can also cause some nasty corruption if one of your clients has a power failure or drops off the network, because this flushing of the local cache to the server can be interrupted.

You used to be able to disable this (on the *client* - so you need to service ALL the clients) on Windows 2000 and XP as per the article, but after Vista SP2 it seems to be impossible.

The comments about not using Access / JetDB as a multi-user database are essentially correct - it's not a good architectural choice, especially in light of the above. DAO is also an obsolete library, even in the obsolete VB6. ADODB is a better choice for VB6, and should allow you some measure of database independence depending on how your app is written.

Answer (score 0):

Since as you pointed out you get decent performance with one user on the system, then obviously your application by nature is not pulling too much data over the network, and we can't blame network speed here.

In fact what is occurring is the windows file share system is switching from single file share mode into multi-share file mode. This switching file modes causes a significant delay.  And this also means that the 2nd or more user has to attempt to figure out and setup locks on the file.

To remove this noticable delay simply at the start of your application open what we call a persistent connection.  A persistent connection is simply something that forces the network connection to remain open at all times, and therefore this significant delay in switching between two file modes for file share is eliminated. You now find that performance with two users should be the same as one (assuming one user is idle and not increasing network load). So at application startup time, open a back end table to a global var and KEEP that table open at all times.